# How fix problem Unexpected in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I developed function in javascript, but I have a problem when reading the data (Get), I have an error Unespected.

also, when I tested in postman, it displays:

> Unexpected ''

this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'desc' of null at dataF
>   (view_rh.html:586)

```
function dataF(node, leaves, index) {
  leaves.push({
    id: ++index,
    text: node.desc
  });
  if (node.children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      index = dataF(node.children[i], leaves, index)[0];
    }
  }
  return [index, leaves];
}

d3.json("getJson.jsp?dataType=rh", function(data) { 

     spinner.stop();     
     allRHJson=data;    
     select2_data_all = dataF(allRHJson,[],0)[1];       
     loadJson(null,allRHJson, select2_data_all ) ;       

     //d3.json(json, loadJson );
});
```

Comment: Clearly `node` is null, what are you passing into the function?

Comment: How you are calling `dataF`? error clearly says that value of `node` is null.

Answer (score 0):

The node variable is null. Check how you are setting the value to it.